# How to install dkms?

Tags: mount, dkms

I am a new user to Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to install dkms for virtualbox, but I keep getting a window that says " CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS *Trusty Tahr* - Release amd64 (20150218.1)' is required

Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/media/cdrom/' to install software packages from it."

A) I don't have a live CD
B) I somehow mounted my iso to that path before, trying to fix a wifi problem, that has been fixed, but it somehow became unmounted and i can't find the video that i found from YouTube to re-mount it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and remove the CD from the software sources.

Then you will be able to install everything.